# Post Tags not working for Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

community,
I am trying to save tag for custom post type and it is not working as intended.
I am using wp_set_post_tags but it never worked.
When I see the values in the database it shows there but when you see at post level in backend nothing is shown or neither in the listing.

Any help in this regard highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to share your code to get helped.

Comment: Did you tell WP your CPT supports the tags taxonomy? Or did you just use the functions in code and expect it to work? When you say tags do you mean the tags that come bundled with WP, or do you mean a custom taxonomy you created? As Q Studio said, we will need to see your code, use the edit link to add the code to your question